# When logging in directly to an application, will the transmission-daemon run in the background?

Tags: cron, transmission

I have a media computer running Ubuntu 12.04 and XBMC.  I also have flexget and transmission-deamon set up to run automatically every hour with a line in my crontab.

```
@hourly /usr/local/bin/flexget --cron
```

Question is, I open XBMC on this machine by selecting 'XBMC' instead of 'Ubuntu' at the log in screen.  Will my flexget and the transmission-daemon still run in the background?

Answer (score 0):

The transmission daemon will works exactly the same on Ubuntu and XBMC sessions.

I think you should not try to reconfigure the cronfiles, try rather to use config files or gtk interface.

Cordially,